# Not able to access property in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, properties

I have just two classes currently in my spring boot application. First is main main Boot Application class another is a service class. I have declared property source file in Application class as below:

```
@SpringBootApplication 
@PropertySource("classpath:ftp.properties")
public class Application
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSchException, SftpException, IOException
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        FTPService ftpservice = new FTPService();
        ftpservice.ftp();
    }

}
```

Other class is FTPService in which property value in injected using @Value as below:

```
public class FTPService
{
    @Value("${vendor1.server}")
    private String VENDOR1_SERVER;

    public boolean ftp() throws JSchException, SftpException, IOException
    {
        boolean success = false;
        System.out.println("vendor1.server : " + VENDOR1_SERVER);
        return success;
    }
}
```

**It prints null.** Tried annotating FTPService with below annotations as well but didn't worked.
Tried copying properties to application.properties but didn't worked.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:ftp.properties")
```

My properties file in under src/main/resources. Its name is ftp.properties and content is below:

```
vendor1.server = server.com
```

Mine is gradle app with below config:

```
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.6.RELEASE'
id 'java'
}

group = groupName

sourceCompatibility = javaVersion
targetCompatibility = javaVersion

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude group: 'log4j', module: 'log4j'
    exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-jdk14'
    exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}

dependencies {

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: bootVersion
    compile group: 'com.jcraft', name: 'jsch', version: jschVersion

    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: servletVersion
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: jacksonVersion
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: log4jVersion
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: log4jVersion
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: log4jVersion
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: slf4jVersion
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jcl-over-slf4j', version: slf4jVersion
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'log4j-over-slf4j', version: slf4jVersion
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jul-to-slf4j', version: slf4jVersion

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: junitVersion
}
```

Am I missing any annotation or right way to specify property file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property injection doesn't work in your sample because you create the object manually with the `new` keyword. Property injection works only in objects managed by the Spring container.

Annotate the FTPService class with `@Service` and then inject that bean to some place where you would like to execute the `ftp()` method. The `main` method won't work in that case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Annotate `FTPService` with `@Component`
2. Change your main class to be

---

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:ftp.properties")
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner
{

    @Autowired
    FTPService ftpService;

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        ftpService.ftp();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```